# Ideone.com API couldn't send code

Tags: c#, api

I download c# realization of ideone API from here http://ideone.com/api. I use this

```
Object[] ret = client.createSubmission(login, pass, "n = gets", 17, "1", true, true);
```

to send code, but code in link i've got is blank, with input of "1". How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download latest wsdl from http://ideone.com/api/1/service.wsdl and

```
      createSubmission()
```

started to work correctly.